# Can I ask what does this clause mean?

Tags: meaning

> *“the stress mums put on themselves to be exceptional parents, which weighs more heavily than outside pressures.”*

I think I understand every single words but I am just not sure what is it trying to say ... doesn’t it mean those mothers believe they are “exceptional parents”? And what does the “weights more heavily than outside pressure” mean ?

The full context is:

> *What Stresses Us Most?
>
>   Top stresses include money troubles, juggling work and home life, and interestingly, the stress mums put on themselves to be exceptional parents, which weighs more heavily than outside pressures.*

Comment: Here 'weighs more heavily' = bigger burden of expectations. Mothers put the internal pressure of *their own expectations* on themselves and this is a bigger stress than any external pressure (it means they want to be exceptional parents and set very high targets for themselves to achieve as parents. Thus  they create stress for themself.)

Comment: You are most welcome @Tao Mai!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that mums are the ones who create the pressure on themselves to live up to ideals they hold about being "exceptional parents".

This is contrasted with "outside pressures". Examples of these aren't shown, but may presumably include requirements from school, eg to make sure kids are dressed exactly right.

Comment: You're welcome Tao. One thing: we only say "at all" to emphasise a negative, eg "I'm not worried at all". In a positive sentence, use something else. In the sentence you used above we could maybe use an adjective to complement the noun "sense", and say "That makes complete sense".